# Show that this expression is non-zero: $3x - 2\sin x\ne 0$ for $x>0$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to show that for every $ x>0 $:

$$ {3x - 2\sin(x)} \ne 0 $$

I have the intuition, and it's easy to show that for $ x\ge 1 $, since $ \sin $ is bounded then it holds, but I'm not sure how to show it for $ 0<x<1 $

It feels very simple on one hand but I still feel a bit stuck.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $3\cdot 0 - 2\sin(0) = 0$. Now, assume there is an $x_0 > 0$ such that $3x_0-2\sin(x_0) = 0$. What does the mean value theorem say?

Answer (score 4):

we have the known inequality $$\sin(x)\le x$$ from here we get
$$2\sin(x)\le 2x<3x$$

Answer (score 3):

**Lemma:** If $0<x<1$ then $\sin x<x$

**Proof:**
[image]

Thus, if $0<x<1$ then $3x>2x>2\sin x$. Then 
$$3x-2\sin x>0$$

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer draws disagreement from me.  It's perfectly valid and avoids the need for calculus.

Comment: It doesn't avoid calculus because area of a sector cannot be defined without calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = 3x, g(x) = 2\sin x$.

$f'(x) = 3, g'(x) = 2\cos x$.

$g'(0) = 2$

$g''(x) = -2\sin x$, so $g'(x)$ is decreasing for $0<x<1$.

Hence the straight line $y = 3x$ never intersects the curve $y = 2\sin x$ for positive $x$ in that range, and you already know how to show it for $x\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of it , but i am not sure of it.
Suppose $ 3x - 2\sin(x) = 0$ then we get $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \frac{3}{2}$ . Then when we take the limit $x$ tend to $0$ , then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3}{2}$ , thus we will be getting a contradiction.

Errors are welcome.